# Android Ringtone Play crash on 4.2

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, ringtone

I am having problems playing a ringtone on my Nexus 4 running Android 4.2.

When I try and play a RingTone I see the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at android.media.Ringtone.play(Ringtone.java:228)
```

My code is below:

```
RingtoneManager ringtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(context);
ringtoneManager.setType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone ringtone = ringtoneManager.getRingtone(index);
Ringtone ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

if (ringtone != null)
{
    ringtone.play();
}
```

The index value is passed into my method based on a user selection (I present them with the list of ringtones to select). In any case it makes no difference what I set this to the behaviour is always the same.

This code works perfectly when running on my two other devices running 2.3 and 4.0.4.

When I debug I can see that the uri is null in the Ringtone that is returned by the ringtone manager (and is set to a valid value on my other devices).

Am I doing something wrong or could this be a bug in 4.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to check first if the ringtone exists at the position.
So try

**Edit:** try this.

```
RingtoneManager ringtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(ActivityName.this);
ringtoneManager.setType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
Cursor c = ringtoneManager.getCursor();
Ringtone ringtone = ringtoneManager.getRingtone(index);
ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
if(ringtone != null && ringtoneManager.getRingtoneUri(position) != null){    
    ringtone.play();
}
```

Comment: That will stop my crash, but it doesn't solve the problem of why I cannot play the ringtone. Why would the RingtoneManager return a Ringtone object if I can't play it?

Comment: well, you are asking for the wrong position. I am not sure why it is returning the Ringtone object, but i guess it is programmers responsibility to check whether the ringtone exists

Comment: I am requesting a valid position and I have tried tweaking this to hardwire it to zero (for example). The result is always the same.

Comment: try the edit, call ringtoneManager.getCursor befor getting ringtone

Comment: That has done the job, many thanks! Pretty nasty that this is required but it does at least work.